# calling tsuml2 --glob npm package throws a ParseError message on my angular project

Tags: typescript, uml, nomnoml

I have an angular application I'm trying to run against [tsuml2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsuml2/v/0.10.0) (version 0.10.0), and am experiencing an issue when I run the following command:

```
tsuml2 --glob "./src/**/!(*.d|*.spec).ts"
```

It appears there's an issue in the nomnoml library with the following stack trace:

```
Error: Parse error at line 57 column 169, expected "]" but got end of file ParseError: Parse error at line 57 column 169, expected "]" but got end of file
    at error (z:\mypath\npm\node_modules\tsuml2\node_modules\nomnoml\dist\nomnoml.js:913:19)
    at parseNode (z:\mypath\npm\node_modules\tsuml2\node_modules\nomnoml\dist\nomnoml.js:824:13)
    at parseNodesAndAssocs (z:\mypath\npm\node_modules\tsuml2\node_modules\nomnoml\dist\nomnoml.js:737:24)
    at parsePart (z:\mypath\npm\node_modules\tsuml2\node_modules\nomnoml\dist\nomnoml.js:715:39)
    at parseNode (z:\mypath\npm\node_modules\tsuml2\node_modules\nomnoml\dist\nomnoml.js:815:28)
    at parseNodesAndAssocs (z:\mypath\npm\node_modules\tsuml2\node_modules\nomnoml\dist\nomnoml.js:737:24)
    at parsePart (z:\mypath\npm\node_modules\tsuml2\node_modules\nomnoml\dist\nomnoml.js:715:39)
    at parseNode (z:\mypath\npm\node_modules\tsuml2\node_modules\nomnoml\dist\nomnoml.js:815:28)
    at parseNodesAndAssocs (z:\mypath\npm\node_modules\tsuml2\node_modules\nomnoml\dist\nomnoml.js:737:24)
    at parsePart (z:\mypath\npm\node_modules\tsuml2\node_modules\nomnoml\dist\nomnoml.js:715:39) {
```

Running from VS Code
Anyone know if there is something with the way my files are set up which is causing this error?  Any thoughts would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you forgot a _]_ somehere, doesn't it?

Comment: Indeed - it looks like someone forgot a ] somewhere!  I think files and dependencies are getting concatenated in nomnoml.js

Answer (score 2):

Version 0.10.0 (2023-Feb) of the tsuml2 app relies on nomnoml, which does not support the "#" character in your source files.  The issue with tsuml2 is found [here](https://github.com/demike/TsUML2/issues/23).

In angular the use of # is common in the .component.html files to identify elements that are declared in the .component.ts files.

This will be addressed as a [fix](https://github.com/skanaar/nomnoml/issues/205) in the latest version of nomnoml